# order by desc on column type double is not working in scala dataframework

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to get top 5 vendor based on total invoice column in desc order, but it seems not working.

Here is my schema & dataset.

```
root
 |-- InvoiceVendorName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- TotalInvoice: double (nullable = true)

+--------------------+--------------------+
|   InvoiceVendorName|        TotalInvoice|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|UCSD/SHARP HEALTH...|       4.340777221E7|
|MEDLINE INDUSTRIE...|3.5532045550000355E7|
|CROSS COUNTRY TRA...| 2.035726783999999E7|
|   EPIC SYSTEMS CORP|         1.3199249E7|
|ASD SPECIALTY HEA...|1.2504829989999998E7|
|JURISDICTION D DM...|         1.1998333E7|
|BLUE CROSS OF CAL...|1.1179388599999998E7|
|AMERICAN NATIONAL...|   8414052.699999997|
|     BANC OF AMERICA|  7986946.8100000005|
|EPLUS TECHNOLOGY,...|          6659258.84|
|DEPUY SYNTHES SAL...|   5193524.240000001|
|BOSTON  SCIENTIFI...|          5034415.02|
|ALEXANDRIA REAL E...|          4693296.75|
|ROCHE DIAGNOSTIC ...|          4687701.74|
| CDR ASSOCIATES, LLC|  4073132.3400000036|
|ALVAREZ & MARSAL ...|           3951250.0|
|    ST. JUDE MEDICAL|  3685824.3499999996|
|OPTIMUM HEALTHCAR...|  3493656.8900000006|
|       NUVASIVE, INC|   3355898.239999999|
|EDWARDS LIFESCIEN...|          3314977.11|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

I have tried below query but none of them worked.

```
top_vendor_invoices.orderBy(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col("TotalInvoice").desc).show()
```

Or

```
top_vendor_invoices.orderBy(desc("TotalInvoice")).show()
```

Comment: Could you please share output to know what is not working while doing desc?

Answer (score 0):

> can you try this:

```
scala> var df = Seq(("UCSD/SHARP HEALTH",       4.340777221),("CROSS COUNTRY TRA", 2.035726783999999),("EPIC SYSTEMS CORP",         1.3199249),("MEDLINE INDUSTRIE",3.5532045550000355),("ASD SPECIALTY HEA",1.2504829989999998)).toDF("InvoiceVendorName","TotalInvoice")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [InvoiceVendorName: string, TotalInvoice: double]

scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- InvoiceVendorName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- TotalInvoice: double (nullable = false)


scala> df.orderBy($"TotalInvoice".desc).show()
+-----------------+------------------+
|InvoiceVendorName|      TotalInvoice|
+-----------------+------------------+
|UCSD/SHARP HEALTH|       4.340777221|
|MEDLINE INDUSTRIE|3.5532045550000353|
|CROSS COUNTRY TRA| 2.035726783999999|
|EPIC SYSTEMS CORP|         1.3199249|
|ASD SPECIALTY HEA|1.2504829989999997|
+-----------------+------------------+
```

have you look and let me know if you are still facing the issue.